# How do I use PHP Mysql query to get json value inside a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a database table which has one of its column containing a json value. I want to know how i use php mysql query to get the value of "title" and "name" from the "elements" column.

```
id | name | elements
---------------------
 1 | Dan  | { 
                "book": { 
                "0": { "title": "The Oblivion of Hope"  }           
                },
                "author": {
                 "0": { "name": "David Addoteye" },
                 "1": { "date": "2015-93-13"}
                 }
            }
```

`elements => book => 0 => title`

`elements => author=> 0 => name`

I will be glad if someone can help me solve this, thank you.

Comment: you need to get record from the table and assign them to a variable by decoding it. that will act like an array and you can use it as you want? fetching data is just normal, no extra effort needed. By querying only you cannot get it directly.

Comment: You can't extract the data directly with a query. You'll need to extract the JSON string from the column then decode it with `json_decode ()`.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the entry from the database and use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn it into an associative array.

http://repl.it/msZ

Some example code:

```
// Equivalent of obtained from DB query.
$fetched_value = '{"book":{"0":{"title":"The Oblivion of Hope"}},"author":{"0":{"name":"David Addoteye"},"1":{"date":"2015-93-13"}}}';

$decoded = json_decode($fetched_value, true);

echo $decoded['book'][0]['title'];
echo $decoded['author'][0]['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get record `$row` from the database:

```
$json = json_decode($row['elements']);
echo $json->book->{0}->title;
```

http://ideone.com/9yV33F